# Can my familiar feed me a potion?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, actions, familiars, potions

The SRD says [potions](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/potions) can be administered by others with a full-round action:

> Drinking a potion or using an oil is a standard action. The potion or oil takes effect immediately. Using a potion or oil provokes attacks of opportunity.
>
> [...]
>
> A character can carefully administer a potion to an [unconscious](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Unconscious) creature as a full-round action, trickling the liquid down the creature's throat.

Can my familiar feed me while I'm conscious and in combat? If so, does it require expenditure of effort larger than a free action by the imbiber? Would the imbiber provoke AoOs? Can I get a [drinking](https://www.google.ca/search?tbm=isch&q=drinking+hat) [tumor](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist/discoveries/paizo---alchemist-discoveries/tumor-familiar-ex)?

Comment: Coincidence: I just used my familiar to feed me a potion and a good berry on two separate turns in 5E. Ravens are smart!

Comment: Is this part of a larger plan to have your pet raven feed you grapes?

Comment: @GMJoe No, but I like your hedonistic thinking and skepticism. Here's some meta-XP.

Answer (score 2):

The limits would ultimately be up to your GM. But consider this:

- Your familiar has an empathic link to you, would know that you are in danger and need assistance.
- Your familiar is intelligent and can make its own decisions.
- Your familiar would be familiar with equipment you have and could know what it is capable of, depending on dialogue with your familiar.
- Your familiar may need to be physically capable of doing the action for you. For example, a rodent would be more capable of manipulating an object with its hands in order to hold the potion, open the cork, and pour/spill it into your mouth while also prying your mouth open in order to administer it. A snake on the other hand, would have a little difficulty of performing such an act, and would require some very clever roleplaying before your GM "buys off" on the idea.
- Your familiar would be subject to all rules within combat that you would be. If your familiar provokes an attack of opportunity, then the potion could be a target, since it would be held by the creature provoking the opportunity, under the [Damaging Objects](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/damaging-objects) rules.
- If you have the prerequisites to obtain a tumor, then yes you would be able to have one - it would be a little harder to pull off if you are not an Alchemist. If you are unconscious, how would the tumor benefit from a potion in order to administer it to you? If you are conscious, then there shouldn't be too much of a problem.
- The tumor resembles an animal, not an article of clothing. But ask
  your GM - he may like the idea and allow you to go along with it.

Comment: Did you, too, misread *conscious* as *unconscious*?

Comment: I don't believe this answers the question as asked - In particular the Action Economy involved and if an AoO is provoked - Would the potion be eligible as a sunder target?

Comment: @Nyoze There were many questions asked. Many questions answered. Edited to accomodate Sunder target.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Yes... yes I did.